# How do i get my visitor counter in my code to show up on the client side or how do i get my value to become an integer

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

My code's purpose is to reach into a database and increment the value of the counter by 1 and while my code does that I am having issues displaying this data to the client side. i am not able to just json.dumps my response variable because dynamodb automatically turns my value into a decimal for some reason. I was able to get it to print using `responseBody = json.dumps({"ID": int(response["Attributes"]["Counter"])})` however it is showing up on the webpage with {"ID": "x"} I want just the X value which is being incremented and not anything else. does anyone know how I can do this? It would be much appreciated. the entirety of my python code is below.

```
import json
import boto3

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('Visitors')

Key = {"ID": {"0"}}
def lambda_handler (event, context):

    response = table.update_item(
        Key={
            "ID": 0
        },
        ExpressionAttributeNames = {
            "#c": "Counter"
        },
        UpdateExpression= "set #c = #c + :val",
        ExpressionAttributeValues={
            ":val": 1
        },
    ReturnValues= "UPDATED_NEW"
    )
   
    responseBody = json.dumps({"ID": int(response["Attributes"]["Counter"])})
    
    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "headers": {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'OPTIONS,POST,GET'
            },
        'body': (responseBody)
        }
```

Comment: what is wrong with the current code? try `'body': {'counter':responseBody}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are receiving `{"ID": "x"}` because that's what you are writing into the body. If you only want to return the number, you can change it to

```py
responseBody = response["Attributes"]["Counter"]

return {
    "statusCode": 200,
    "headers": {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'OPTIONS,POST,GET'
    },
    'body': responseBody
}
```

Potentially, you'd need to convert it to a string, or do other adjustments, based on what exactly `response["Attributes"]["Counter"]` returns you.

The essence is, that you get exactly what you put into the `body` attribute. So if you don't want to have `"ID":` in there, just leave it out.

Answer (score 0):

Just return the response["Attributes"]["Counter"] as the responseBody value and then pass that into tour body within the return statement. You can alter the value into a string or integer or whatever you need before returning it if you need to.